# How to use the same partialview for different tables with the same structure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm building a portal to manage process set-points for different products, each process Area has a number of tables (with the same structure, 5 int, 10 real) that store set-points (AreaXSetpointInfoY with Area number X and SetpoinIntfo table Y) and a GeneralProductInfo table (all that in SQL linked by Entity Framework using database first). The main achievement is to get a view to edit both the GeneralInfo and a specified AreaXSetpointInfoY table.

I already achieved the following view, it uses a main view and a view rendered inside from an @HTML.Action now with just one specific table.

[view to achive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rjZU.png)

As the number of tables and areas can change at some point in the future, I would like to have them at least in a combobox and when another AreaXSPInfoY table is selected re-render the table part of the view.

I already though or tried different approaches,

1. Have a ViewModel that could be dynamically bind depending on parameters such Area, SPInfo, ProductID.
2. Other approach is to use a stored procedure which returns the columns of selected AreaXSPInfoY table and render it in the view.
3. Or to use a raw query to get the columns from the desired AreaXSPInfoY table

The problems with these tries are:

1.a I haven't found a way to dynamically bind a model to a table (I know that when the time comes to add more AreaXSPInfoY tables they should be 
added to the EF model)

2.a I have already built a stored procedure to achieve this but when I try to use it as a function of the entity it simply doesn't appear in the entity definition (I already added to the model as Function Import, it returns a complex type, etc.)

```vb
Public Function ProductDetailAreaXSPIY(_parameters As AreaXSPInfoXParameters) As ActionResult
    Dim model = _db.Database.GetAreaXSPInfoY(_parameters.AreaID, _parameters.SPInfoID, _parameters.ProductID)

    ViewData("Message") = "Tabla: "
    If model Is Nothing Then
        Return HttpNotFound()
    End If

    Return View(model)
End Function
```

This would definitely work for the purpose.

3.a Since the stored procedure approach couldn't be, I thought of using raw query to the database

```vb
Public Function ProductDetailAreaXSPIY(_parameters As AreaXSPInfoXParameters) As ActionResult
    Dim _SQLquery As String = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Area" + _parameters.AreaID.ToString() + "SPInfo" + _parameters.SPInfoID.ToString() + 
            " WHERE dbo.Area" + _parameters.AreaID.ToString() + "SPInfo" + _parameters.SPInfoID.ToString() + ".ProductID = " + _parameters.ProductID.ToString()
    Dim model = _db.Database.SqlQuery(_SQLquery)

    ViewData("Message") = "Tabla: "
    If model Is Nothing Then
        Return HttpNotFound()
    End If

    Return View(model)
End Function
```

The problem here is that I need to specify the type of the returning query and I don't know which would it be or how to do it.

Right now the above showed view comes from the following controller ActionResult

```vb
' GET: SPInfo/ProductDetail/ProductID partial view for area X setpointinfo Y
Public Function ProductDetailAreaXSPIY(Optional ByVal id As Integer = 0) As ActionResult
    ViewData("Message") = "Tabla: "
    Dim model As Area1SetpointInfo1 = _db.Area1SetpointInfo1.Find(id)
    If model Is Nothing Then
       Return HttpNotFound()
    End If

    Return View(model)

End Function
```

Comment: I haven't actually read your post but the table structure is actually irrelevant.  What matters is the model.  All your view cares about is the model.  If you can fit the data from various sources into the same model then you can use the same view.  It's that simple.  Instead of using what comes from your `_db.Database` as the model, define a model class specifically for that view, then map what you get from the database into that.  The view cares nothing for the database.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, actually is what I am trying to achieve.